# Compare the data of two string and then save the matching data on other string

Tags: c#, generics

I have two string, and I want to compare these two string and then save the matching data. I can achieve this by using foreach loop as shown below in the code, but I dont want to use it. Just wanted to know other syntax that can be used for it. Below is the code I used this to achieve with the help of foreach:

```
//matching the string data with the help of foreach to get the result

List<string> roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser().ToList();
RoleResponse response = application.GetAuthorizedSecurityRoles();
foreach (string r in roles)
        {
            foreach (string securityRole in responses.SecurityRoles)
            {
                if (r == securityRole)
                {
                    result.Add(roles);
                }
            }
        }
return result;
```

How can I get the matching result in another string without using foreach. Can this be achive via join method?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't want to use foreach loop then go for RegEx

Comment: I don't really see the connection between the question you asked and the code you posted. If you "can achieve this by using foreach loop" it might help, if you show this solution (even if you don't like it) so we'll have a better understanding of what you want to do and how it should work. Then maybe we can help you find a way to do it better.

Comment: @Corek: I have modified my question for a better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Well, using `LINQ` you *could* write that like `return responses.SecurityRoles.Where(role == securityRole);`, but that would still use foreach in the background.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `return roles.Intersect(responses.SecurityRoles);`. - but still, the `foreach` is just hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace your `foreach` loop with the code below

```
List<string> lstResponses = new List<string>
lstResponses = responses.SecurityRoles
result = (from r in roles
          join securityRole in lstResponses on r equals securityRole
          select r).ToList()
```

Please Share the Results

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)